# Does Docebo web api support Swagger?

Tags: swagger, webapi

I am wondering if Docebo LMS ([https://www.docebo.com/](https://docebo.com)) web api supports Swagger or not. I contacted their technical support. But they don't know what I talked about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

You have to activate a new trial platform and once you get it, you will have an URL such as:

> yourtrialplatfrom.docebosaas.com

Now you just need to append "\api-browser" to your URL

> yourtrialplatfrom.docebosaas.com\api-browser

You can now, from this URL Access the Swagger API